# What is the correct indention for pep8 on long lines with argument list and assignment

Tags: python, django, pep8

What is the correct indention for this scenario:

```
class StorageType(models.Model):
    """ Defining a general typ of storage """

    name = models.CharField(
            max_length=50,
            help_text=_("The name for a storage type. Should be unique")
        )
```

pep8 complains with

```
../models.py:68:13: E126 continuation line over-indented for hanging indent
../models.py:70:9: E121 continuation line under-indented for hanging indent
```

Comment: Why not consult [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) itself? Note that the `pep8` program (which is not endorsed by the official Python developers, by the way) is more rigid than the actual PEP 8 guidelines.

Comment: In fact I did it but the above was the extract I was understanding. So I have to admit there is some potential on my side -- at least on reading/understanding it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know about the "correct one", but here's my favorite which passes `pep8` check:

```
name = models.CharField(
    max_length=50,
    help_text=_("The name for a storage type. Should be unique")
)
```

Answer (score 6):

This is *one* correct indentation:

```
class StorageType(models.Model):
    """ Defining a general typ of storage """

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        help_text=_("The name for a storage type. Should be unique")
        )
```